# Medical history for medical examination in London for US visa

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, immigration, k1-visa, medical

I am in the process for a K1 visa and I have my medical examination at Knigthsbridge Doctors in London in 2 weeks. I have a few doubts:

**1.** I am from Italy and have lived in the UK for almost 3 years now. I have all the [documents necessary for my medical](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/fiancee-2/medical-examination/). I recently got from my GP the patient care summary too (that is a new requirement that is not on the UK embassy list).
I was wondering whether I need my medical records from Italy too, it's not specified anywhere! (It is specified instead for criminal records)

Question 1 on [their questionnaire](https://uk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2017/05/USA-MEDICAL-QUESTIONNAIRE_IV.pdf) asks if you've ever been hospitalised and I had to put YES: I got into a car accident in Italy (been in hospital under observation only), had a head trauma with temporary amnesia in Italy and a kidney infection in the UK (due to episode of kidney stones). I explained all these 3 in an attachment to the questionnaire. Do I need to find and take with me all the translated documentation from Italy? (it would be a problem to get them in time)

**2.** In case I find out only when I'm at the medical that they also need info from my Italian records can they simply access them themselves or do I have to provide them (translated) afterwards therefore causing delays in my visa process?

**3.** I put NO on the question that asks "Have you ever had any kidney or liver disease" as it was only a single episode, nothing chronic. Is that correct?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I'm getting some answers to the above also [HERE](http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/663350-patient-care-summary-from-home-country/) and [HERE](http://britishexpats.com/forum/marriage-based-visas-35/patient-care-summary-necessary-home-country-too-909589/#post12448297).

REQUIREMENTS GIVEN BY THE PHYSICIAN IN LONDON (Knightsbridge Doctors):

[image: Knightsbridge Doctors London - required documents list]

Comment: I have no experience with your first two questions, however, I would answer yes for your third answer because it doesn't ask you if you have a chronic disease. It just asks you if you have ever had any kidney disease. However, kidney stone is quite common and is not enough grounds for a rejection on medical grounds.

Comment: Well I put the description of that single episode under the hospitalisation section. Maybe it's enough?
I read a few articles that said kidney stones lead to kidney disease (so it's not a disease itself..)

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards: Kidney stones are a form of kidney disease (https://www.kidney.org/blog/ask-doctor/having-kidney-stones-considered-having-kidney-disease) so you should answer yes. If the doctor needs something from your medical records that you did not bring, they will unlikely be able to access them directly and it can cause delays in the visa application.

As to what information you need, the instructions are vague. The [main medical exam page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/family-immigration/nonimmigrant-visa-for-a-fiance-k-1.html#7) says nothing. The [interview page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/the-immigrant-visa-process/interview/interview-prepare/medical-examination.html) says to bring *Copies of your medical history records*. The [medical exam FAQ](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/the-immigrant-visa-process/interview/interview-prepare/medical-examination-faqs.html) says

> The applicant must show his/her passport (or other photo identification) and appointment letter to the doctor during the medical examination.
>
> The medical examination will include a medical history review, physical examination, chest X-ray and blood tests for syphilis.

and does not mention medical records anywhere.

The only mention of records, apart from immunization records, that I can find is in the [London Embassy instructions](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/iv-dv-supplemental/LND-London.pdf) which says to bring records regarding TB treatment.

There are no instructions at all about translating medical records.

My personal strategy would be to bring what I have and not stress about it.

Comment: The Patient Care Summary is a new requirement that has been added in April 2017. It is not listed on the UK consulate website yet.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the requirements to the original question

Comment: Medical examination passed. I put YES as you suggested for kidney illnesses.

Answering question 1: I managed to get a certificate from my last doctor in my home country and handed that in at the reception together with the other documents even though they were not sure whether they needed it.
I was not asked for any documentation about the hospitalisations.